# In the UV Editing mode, how do i rotate the camera on the left side of the split screen?

Tags: uv

Noob question. How do i turn the camera of the left side of the split screen in UV editing mode?[image]

Comment: Hello :). Select all vertices and use the rotate tool. You can't rotate the view in UV editor.

Comment: The person that im following on youtube had the table top from the topview. Do you know what i have done wrong?

Comment: Hello :). You need your *viewport camera* to look from top, before you unwrap from view. Go *View > Viewpoint > Top* and then unwrap. Check the tutorial again, you just missed a step :).

Comment: Or, if the tabletop is not conveniently aligned to World Z, selct the face in Edit mode, and hit Shift - Numpad 7 to look straight down on it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is no-can-do. I dont believe u can do it in blender given that the uv editing window works like image view window.

i Guess what u wanna achieve is that ur uv looks like the top view ? And based on the uv, You probably unwrapped it from the view. If so, on the right 3D Viewport, change ur view to top and unwrap it from the view again should suit ur need. BUt I Suggest u do "smart uv project"

Go watch a proper UV unwarp tutorial will make ur life easier